# Access mysql DB and pass to an Objective-C app

Tags: python, mysql, objective-c

How can I build a script with Python to access a MySQL database and pass data to an Objective-C app?

Comment: Concentrate on getting the python to access the data and produce a JSON output first. Then have objc to access and deserialise. What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm just had this idea, because I saw some topics about using PHP for it, but I'm not familiar with PHP. So I thought it would be better to use Python, which I'm more familiarized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think use python to fetch data is so simple;
there are many `ORM` s , e.g., you can use `SQLAlchemy` ;
after you get the data, the problem is I think the Objective-C app.
does it have any interface to access data?

Comment: What do you mean with interface to access data?

Comment: for example, is there a method supported by Obj-c app I can request to post my data?

Comment: or, just store the data in a specific file, then you Obj-c app read the data from files

Comment: Ok, do you think there is a tutorial for this or something like a open source app with this?

Comment: I think you don't understand what the goal the stackoverflow has, and I think this is a real bad question, please try before you ask!